# Minimal custom linux live cd with only essential software and least effort possible

Tags: linux, live-cd

I want to build a custom linux live cd with only the absolutely essential software for my purpose:

- run 1-3 simple web apps based on flask (python)
- run 1-3 simple web apps based on sinatra (ruby)
- run 1-3 simple web apps based on php
- sqlite3 databases created on the fly
- ssh server
- NO X server
- it has to be Linux, not other OS

It's not intended for actually burning to a cd, 
but to boot the iso file with a virtualization software (such as virtual box, vmware), 
creating a clean new demo environment with the web apps on every reboot.

It would be great to fit all this in the smallest size to make it a quick download. But I don't have the time or energy to learn building linux from scratch, so I'm willing to compromise on size and try to strip down an existing distro that is already tiny to begin with. But which one?

**UPDATE**

I ended up using [TinyCore](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/), and I was pretty happy with it! I built a hacking contest into it, all in less than 30 MB. You can download the CD from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctfomatic/files/) and give it a spin in any virtualization software, or even boot your PC with it. The source code of the remastering scripts is on [GitHub](https://github.com/janosgyerik/ctf-o-matic).

Comment: Ask at ubuntu or linux forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and how about making this one live (Jeoss)....

http://www.vercot.com/~jeoss/default.html

Comment: Hm, thanks, but at 138MB it's much bigger than other options (damn small linux ~ 50MB)

Comment: those 138MB include the optional packages that you can erase, the big difference with dsl is that Jeoss is a real ubuntu with packet manager then you can add whatever you want by apt-get ...

Comment: isn't dsl debian based? in which case i get all the same apt-get heaven as jeoss.

Comment: dsl has not package manager, you can add the debian one but there's a blured line where all debian packages really work or not on dsl. Jeoss works with Ubuntu repositories out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Suse Studio](http://www.susestudio.com). It allows you to make your own custom image online - you only download .iso image. You can customize everything and it's based on OpenSuse.

Comment: Do you know how big the smallest possible image can be?

Comment: No, I do not know that. You can remove evrything though so look for the size of stripped OpenSuse image size.

Answer (score 1):

[This is what you want.](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) As small as possible.